# (Almost) fill a square with non-overlapping circles

Tags: geometry, limits

How do I put a finite number of non-overlapping circles into a square, so that their total area approaches the area of the square as the number of the circles approaches infinity? Their radius can vary.

This looks obvious to me, but I am unable to give it a formal proof. I tried induction, but I am unable to track the area of the smaller-and-smaller circles when I keep putting circles into the square.

Comment: What you propose can not be done. The problem is that the total area will never approach the area of the square no matter how you arrange the circles. The Wikipedia article [Circle packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing) states "While the circle has a relatively low maximum packing density of 0.9069 on the Euclidean plane,...".

Comment: If you make each circle as large as possible when you place it the uncovered space will be "triangles" with edges that bend inward because they are pieces of circles.  If you can prove that a circle placed in such a triangle occupies a fraction of the area that is bounded away from $0$ you are done.  Each time you go around and put a circle in each remaining region you decrease the unused area by a factor bounded away from $1$.  You can compute the radius of the inscribed circle from the radii of the bounding circles by [Decartes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_theorem)

Comment: I suspect the challenge will come when two sides of the "triangle" have a radius much large than the third, so the "triangle" is long and narrow.  You may be able to describe a chain of circles down the long direction that has a fractional area bounded away from $0$.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing sounds like an [Apollonian gasket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonian_gasket) for the square.  Obviously, one would begin with a single circle inscribed in the square; then the four corner shapes can be filled recursively in a symmetric fashion.  The centers and radii of the circles can be calculated using the [complex Descartes' circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_theorem).  This is indeed a space-filling packing.

Comment: I think we are asked to prove it is space filling

Answer (score 0):

To set the record straight: The relevant term here is **Vitali covering lemma**. You can find this (and most probably a corollary that non-touching circles can fill a square with the non-covered area approaching zero) in any standard real analysis book.